# fetch the value from the data table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables users,project,department.I want to get 'owner_id'(DCE005) from project table and get the user_id (2) from users table and get the PM_dceid (DCE003) of the project owner and check (DCE003) not in department table's 'dept_head'  column.If (DCE003) not in dept_head(DCE004,DCE007,DCE009) then get the value (3) from the users table.Is it possible to get recursive data

```
project table
 id  owner_id  dept_id  
  4  DCE005     005

users table
 user_id dceid    name    PM_dceid
  1  DCE001  user1    DCE003
  2  DCE005  user2    DCE003
  3  DCE003  user3    DCE009

Department table 
 id    dept-id   dept_head
  2       005      DCE004
  3       006      DCE007
  4                DCE009  

query
 $dept= department::pluck('dept_head')->all();
$project=DB::table('project')
      ->join('users', 'project.project_owner_id', '=', 'users.aceid')->whereNotIn('users.id', $dept)
```

Comment: Yes, you have to use `join` as well as `self` join

Comment: can you give some example

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. use nested selects along with In not in keywords.

Would be something like this:

`DB::select(DB::raw('select * from users, IF((SELECT users.PM_dceid FROM project, users WHERE project.owner_id = users.dceid AND project.owner_id= (SELECT owner_id FROM project LIMIT 1)) NOT IN (SELECT  dept_head FROM Department))  WHERE id = " '.$yorKey.'" '));`

Comment: can you give example

Comment: `get the value (3) from the users table`. did you mean select another user form db?